# Google analytics Unversial migrate to V4

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4, gtag.js

I recently want to migrate analytics.js to gtag.js.

But my javascript code include some GTM inclusion.

```
ga('require', 'OPT_XXXXXXX');
ga('require', 'GTM-XXXXXXX');
```

My question is that how to implement GTM in Google Analytic V4 gtag.js?

Comment: Have you checked the docs?  [UA→GA4 Migration reference](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10607999?hl=en)  GA4 is not a small change.  Can you be more specific as to what you need help migrating.

Answer (score 0):

The API has shifted around a bit from when [analytics.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/command-queue-reference) was used to the current [gtag.js](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/gtagjs/reference) approach. The mechanism for incorporating the GA tag with GTM has changed. I would advise getting away from direct API calls unless necessary.

Instead install a GTM container directly to your page and load the new GA4 configuration and any necessary GA4 event tags from there as needed, letting it call the underlying gtag API as it needs to.

I don't know the reference to OPT_XXXXXXX in your sample, but you might look at whatever vendor that's from and look to their guidance in how to install via GTM and run alongside GA4.